# JibXvs XStream - when the Domain Object is yet to be constructed

Tags: xstream, jibx

I am working on a conversion between XML to Java Object work packet. Here, Java object type is not defined and hence I am thinking that XStream will not help me with marshalling.

However, if I were to use JiBX I can easily code-generate the Java class (using the XSD of the XML) and then have the marshalling done from an XML to java object.

I want to know if this is the right understanding to choose between JiBX and XStream.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep,

You are correct. JiBX is a better choice when you are starting with a schema definition (XSD) file. JiBX will create the java classes for you using the schema definition.

XStream is a great tool if you already have the java classes and would like to output them as xml.

Don